# How to Update Bindings on bootstrap-daterangepicker date change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date-range

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) with my AngularJS app and variables to store the start and end date whenever they change.

on date range change, how can i call the controller method to update data on the page?

Like calling this method of the scope:

```
$scope.updateDataOnDateRangeChange = function(){
    // here calling few services to fetch new data for the page
    // for the selected date range
}
```

how to use ng-click or ng-change or custom directive for this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Basic procedure for using a jQuery plugin is typically to create a directive for it. Inside the `link` callback you initialize the plugin. Here you have access to the element as jQuery or jQ-lite object, the angular scope , and the plugin callbacks. See important comments about uing `$.apply()` when making changes to scope within third party code

Sample html:

```
<input my-picker type="text"/>
```

Basic script outline:

```
app.directive('myPicker', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            $timeout(function () {
                /* elem is a jQuery or jQ-lite object representing the element*/
                elem.daterangepicker({
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                    startDate: '2013-01-01',
                    endDate: '2013-12-31'
                },
               /* not overly familiar with this plugin but this callback 
                 should allow you to set angular scopes */
                function (start, end) {
                    /* important to do any scope changes within `$.apply()` so angular
                      becomes aware of changes from third party code*/
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        /* do what you need here with angular scope
                         have access to plugin data as well as angular scope*/

                    })
                });
            }, 1)
        }
    }

})
```

You could enhance this directive by adding other attributes to markup and then using the attributes to set various plugin options also.

Comment: thanks alot. i shall give it a try. and yes within this function (start, end) {} which is the callback function, i guess i can call my Service to update data for the selected date range

Comment: yes...exactly. Add the service as dependency to directive also. `app.directive('myPicker', function ($timeout, TheServiceIWant) {....`

Answer (score 0):

There is an [ngChange directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChange) present within AngularJS which should do what you describe.

Add this directive to your date range input element.

Comment: not likely to fire since browsers don't recognize a change event when value is changed with script